# Magento 1.6.2 got double prefix while calling createEntityTables during custom eav entity setup

Tags: magento

Followed Alan Storm's tutorial, and I got some problem while calling createEntityTables() method. My script is like:

```
$installer->createEntityTables(
    $this->getTable('complexworld/eavblogpost')
);
```

I've solved the problem related to BLOB/TEXT Mysql error, but another problem occurred. The tables I created have double prefix ("mgt_" is the prefix),

```
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_char
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_datetime
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_decimal
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_int
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_text
mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts_varchar
```

Tried to dig in createEntityTables() method, and while I print $this->getTable($baseTableName),

```
if (!$isNoCreateMainTable) {
        /**
         * Create table main eav table
         */
        echo $this->getTable($baseTableName);
        exit;
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
```

I got "mgt_mgt_eavblog_posts" on the screen, which means the core method may have added an extra prefix to the table name. Any idea what's going wrong here? I appreciate all your kind helps!

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. It must be broken in the core module. Seems odd in such a mature product. Did you report this bug?

Answer (score 5):

$table = strtolower(substr(ltrim($this->getTable('complexworld/eavblogpost')), strlen(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix())));

$installer->createEntityTables($table);